# Use $HOSTNAME in sed substitution

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, hostname

I want to use my Centos VM's $HOSTNAME inside a call to `sed` like so:

```
sed -i 's/Apache 2 Test Page/$HOSTNAME Test Page/g' /var/www/error/noindex.html
```

But this just replaces `Apache 2 Test Page` with `$HOSTNAME Test Page`... I know I can do it manually, but I've got a good reason for wishing to do it this way.

---

*FWIW, I'm actually doing this inside a bash script that gets called from a Vagrantfile, which in turn provisions multiple VM's (each with Apache2 installed), so that I can test-out the load-balancing capabilities of HAProxy. so I just want a simple way to differentiate between my 3 web-servers, and II figure that modifying the default Apache page is the easiest way to do that.*

Comment: Enclose sed's(`s///`) with double quotes instead single quotes for variable expansion.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, this would be ok here too. I prefer the solution I've posted, because then I don't have to worry about escaping shell characters in the sed command. (Which aren't a problem in this case)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enclose `sed`'s `s///` with double quotes instead of single quotes for variable expansion.

```
sed -i "s/Apache 2 Test Page/$HOSTNAME Test Page/g" /var/www/error/noindex.html
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'foo Apache 2 Test Page bar' | sed "s/Apache 2 Test Page/$HOSTNAME Test Page/g"
foo avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500 Test Page bar
```